# How to pass delegate between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have three View Controllers. Let's call them BaseVC, firstVC and secondVC. FirstVC is presented modally by BaseVC. SecondVC is pushed by firstVC. There is a one button on each firstVC and secondVC. By clicking them, I want to dismiss the current VC and let BaseVC do something. So I created a protocol, let BaseVC obey it, and set BaseVC as firstVC's delegate. When I set secondVC's delegate from firstVC, breakpoint show it succeeding. However when I call delegate from secondVC, it shows _delegate is nil.

Is it because delegate is always a `weak` property? So how could I pass delegate between View Controllers or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: "When I set secondVC's delegate from firstVC..." Can you post the code for this?

Comment: Delegate is weak as to not create circular references. BaseVC, being underneath secondVC & thirdVC, has a guaranteed longer lifecyle than any of these pushed VC.

Comment: Just in the `prepareforSegue` method, I set `((secondVC *)destinationViewController).delegate = self.delegate` @ZeMoon

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare Since when secondVC's running, BaseVC as delegate is still available. So why I see secondVC's delegate is nil in secondVC's breakpoint, while see it is not nil in firstVC's breakpoint~

Comment: It will be my pleasure to answer this. Please post sample code here or on GitHub for review.

Answer (score 1):

You can use postNotification while dismissing the VC and add the observer on baseVC to do some operation.

You could use `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in button action to dismiss the view controller.

Before this you need to post the notification `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificaitonBaseVC" object:nil];` and add the observer in baseVC's viewDidLoad method as follows

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomeOperation:) name:@"NotificaitonBaseVC" object:nil];
```

Comment: This does work. And I choose this as my final solution. But I also want to understand, why can't I pass delegate between the two VCs.

Comment: You can use delegate between 2 VC but here you have to maintain the delegates on 3 VC. So i think the better solution is the above one. Also i want to know that what is the problem you are facing on the above code?

Comment: I see secondVC's delegate is nil in secondVC's breakpoint, while see it is not nil in firstVC's breakpoint. It means I didn't successfully pass the value~ As for NSNitificationCenter, I didn't meet any problems~